# Unix sort string and number together

Tags: string, unix, sorting, numbers

I have what I think should be a common problem, but I didn't find any good solution for it yet.

I have a file where each line has a chromosome number, a starting position in the chromosome and some related values, like below.

```
1       1.07299851019   1       1.07299851019   HQ      chrY    2845223         +       0.251366120219  46      
1       1.06860686763   1       1.06860686763   HQ      chr10   88595309        +       0.256830601093  47      
1       1.04688316093   3       3.14064948278   HQ      chr6    49126474        +       0.295081967213  54      
1       1.1563829915    1       1.1563829915    HQ      chrX    16428176        +       0.185792349727  34
```

I want to sort this file using unix sort command both on chromosome (column 6) and starting position (column 7). After searching around I came up with this, which got me fairly close:

```
nohup sort -t $'\t' -k 6.4,6.5n -k 7,7n
```

The remaining problem that I can't solve is that while chromosomes numbered with a number is sorted alright chromosome X and chromosome Y are sorted together on starting position like this:

```
1       0.978579587641  9       8.80721628876   HQ      chrX    2861057 -       0.431693989071  79      
1       0.979500536702  1       0.979500536702  HQ      chrY    2861314 -       0.420765027322  77      
1       0.969979601694  9       8.72981641525   HQ      chrX    2861649 -       0.469945355191  86
```

I know it would be possible to solve e.g. by replacing chrX and chrY with numbers, or write a program to solve it, but it would be super nice to be able to use a simple command, especially since the file sizes often are huge and I do this repeatedly.

It would also be nice if the chromosomes line up in order 1 to 22 and then X and then Y. My command had chromosome X and Y coming first and then chromosome 1 to 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To separate `X` from `Y`, you can specify a fallback key:

```
nohup sort -t $'\t' -k 6.4,6.5n -k 6 -k 7,7n
```

(this says that if two rows are equivalent in the field `6.4,6.5` as compared numerically, then the next step is to compare them in the field `6` *non*-numerically, before trying field `7`).

Disclaimer: this doesn't satisfy the goal in your last paragraph:

> It would also be nice if the chromosomes line up in order 1 to 22 and then X and then Y. My command had chromosome X and Y coming first and then chromosome 1 to 22.

because `X` and `Y` will still be treated as zero during the numeric sort, and the fallback won't change that. Hopefully you find it useful anyway.

> I know it would be possible to solve e.g. by replacing chrX and chrY with numbers, […]

Indeed, you can do that replacement on the fly:

```
sed 's/chrX/chr23/; s/chrY/chr24/' |
  sort -t $'\t' -k 6.4,6.5n -k 7,7n |
  sed 's/chr23/chrX/; s/chr24/chrY/'
```

(Note that the line-breaks in this command are optional; I included them for readability, but you can put this on one line, if you want, if/when you actually use it.)

Comment: Thank you very much ruakh, the sed command does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

If your version of `sort` supports the `-V` option which is meant for sorting alphanumeric columns then you can do something like:

```
$ cat file
1   1.07299851019   1   1.07299851019   HQ  chrY    2845223     +   0.251366120219  46
1   1.06860686763   1   1.06860686763   HQ  chr10   88595309    +   0.256830601093  47
1   1.04688316093   3   3.14064948278   HQ  chr6    49126474    +   0.295081967213  54
1   1.1563829915    1   1.1563829915    HQ  chrX    16428176    +   0.185792349727  34
```

```
$ sort -t$'\t' -k6V -k7n file
1   1.04688316093   3   3.14064948278   HQ  chr6    49126474    +   0.295081967213  54
1   1.06860686763   1   1.06860686763   HQ  chr10   88595309    +   0.256830601093  47
1   1.1563829915    1   1.1563829915    HQ  chrX    16428176    +   0.185792349727  34
1   1.07299851019   1   1.07299851019   HQ  chrY    2845223     +   0.251366120219  46
```

Comment: Thank you JS, this seems to be what I want. Unfortunately my version doesn't support the -V option.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on jaypal's answer from before...

You can change the sort criteria **per column** like so:

`sort -k1,1V input.txt`

This will sort column 1 and only column 1 using the aforementioned `-V` option which is as follows quoted from [here](http://azaleasays.com/2014/02/21/sort-chromosome-names-with-linux-sort/).

> What -V means is “natural sort of (version) numbers within text” (type
>   man sort to find out), and it magically orders numbers and texts.

If you have multiple columns in a tab delimited file and you want to specify the primary column sort order you can do something like the following:

`sort -k14,14V -k1,1n input.txt`

The above will use column 14 as the first sort index and apply the `-V` sorting alogrithm, then will use column 1 as the secondary sort index and use numeric sorting.  (This might be useful in some circles for sorting by chromosome and then position).

To address the missing `-V` option for OSX users:

> The Mac OS X native sort does not support -V, you’ll have
>   to install GNU core utilities and use gsort instead.

For a quick look at how `-V` sorting will work you can see the below example...

Example input:

```
chr21   
chr2    
chr3    
chrY    
chr1    
chr3    
chr10   
chrX
```

V sorted output:

```
chr1    
chr2    
chr3    
chr3    
chr10   
chr21   
chrX    
chrY
```